# как вывести пустые строки между id SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Есть запрос на вывод расписания для учителя. Мне необходимо показать в запросе окна в расписание.

Запрос:

```
SELECT pos_in_day, Object_.name_object, CONCAT(id_specialization, '-', number_course, char_group, commerce) AS groups 
FROM Object_, Schedules, Group_, Post_Object 
WHERE Schedules.id_object = Post_Object.id_object and day_in_week = 2 and Schedules.id_group = Group_.id_group and Post_Object.id_object = Object_.id_object and Post_Object.id_post = 1 
ORDER BY pos_in_day asc
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Исходное расписание:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видите есть предмет, который не относится к определенному учителю, мне нужно его заменить на пустую строку, чтобы показать окно

Comment: а вы сначала перепишите запрос из формата `from t1,t2,t3..` на `from t1 inner join t2 on (...) ....` а потом нужный джойн исправьте на `left`

Comment: @teran слишком жестко